# Jenkins UI Automation testing

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, jenkins-job-dsl

We have the following UI as shown in the image. These parameters are cascaded i.e they are inter-dependent. If you select continent then respective countries will come and then when you select country respective city will come.

[image]

I want to automate testing of each option. This was just a dummy UI. In my case these fields are dynamic i.e generated on the fly through shell/groovy scripts and I have more than 10 such fields.

I have seen Robot Framework and Job-DSL Plugin but I am not able to write test cases for these option selection. Also I have seen some tools which record your steps and generate a test file according to steps performed based on option selected and buttons clicked?

Can some one guide me for the optimum tool or platform so as to do Automation testing?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is 'the optimal way' but here's what I would do:

I assume that all selections are based on the Jenkins jelly calling a method in your code, I suggest you put the effort in combining these calls in a normal unit test first. There you can try all possibilities in a much faster way.

Then when it comes to real UI test, record a Selenium session and translate that into the source code of your choice.